# F3 Framework Template serve not calling PHP functions

Tags: php, html, fat-free-framework

It seems F3 framework doesn't handle php function calls within a page? I have a php navigation bar, which is uniform site-wide. I call up my layout page in my controller class thus: `Template::serve('layout.php')`. In the layout page, I include the navigation bar thus: `<F3:include href="navbar.php" />`. Within the navbar (navigation) file, I call a utility function siteUrl which gets the absolute url to a resource e.g. css or .js file. This function is defined in an include file which I include as follows: `require_once "lib/globals.php`. Within the navbar.php, I use the siteUrl as follows for example:

```
<img id="logo" alt="logo" src="<?php echo siteUrl('small-logo.png') ?>" />
```

This doesn't seem to work. When I view the generated source of the page, the src section of the img tag is an empty string: "". However, when I call the navigation bar from other pages that are not using the F3 framework (i.e. pages that are not being routed by F3::route. Not all pages of the website are routed using F3), it works fine. 
What could be the problem? How could I call a php function from within a php page that is being rendered using Template::serve? It seems the entire content between the `<?php ?>` tag is not being executed when the page is being served by F3. Echo statements are not being displayed. Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Template::serve()` does not allow PHP.  It is a templating engine.  There are things you can do.  You can define a function using `F3::set('sum',function($a,$b){return 1+2;});` and then reference that function in the template with `{{@sum(1,2)}}`.  I would re-read the templating documentation on the fatfree site: http://bcosca.github.com/fatfree/#views-templates

Again, the reason PHP is not working is because you are using `Template::serve()` and are therefore using the templating features of Fatfree.  If you want to use PHP, I believe you can use `F3::render()` instead and it will render the page, allowing PHP, but you will lose all the templating functionality.

Answer (score 1):

you can use raw php within the template tokens wrapped by curly brakets like this:

```
<img id="logo" alt="logo" src="{{ siteUrl('small-logo.png') }}" />
```

it will echo it automatically.

but using F3::set('image.smallLogo',siteUrl('small-logo.png')) to define the image paths and grap them with a simple {{@image.smallLogo}} feels much better.

Answer (score 0):

page moved:
[Fat-Free Framework 3 Template Directives](http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#template-directives)